# I need Create text on Left side Currently it is on Center . How I left this?

Tags: flutter, layout, alignment

I need This create text on Left  I created simple UI using **flutter**. I have a problem. I need this ***Create***

**Text on Left side**. I didn't add center tag to my code but when **I add devider** to my code the text automatically in center . I want devider but also I want this text on **left align** ? How can I do that ?

My code Flutter

```
     return   Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
         elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: new Center(child: new Text('Create',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black))),
    leading: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_back, 
      color: Colors.black, 
    ),
    ),
       ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
           Divider(
              height: 2,
          color: Colors.red,
          ),
            SizedBox(
            height: 17.0,
            ),
        Container(
            // margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0),

             child: Text('Create')
           )
         ],
       )

          ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your text container.

`alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,`

example:

```
Container(
     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
     child: Text('Create'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've never used flutter but as a front end developer this is the insight I can offer. 
There's two reasons why this could be happening. Either the text is in a container which is not left aligned or the Text object is not left aligned.

To go about fixing this the first thing I would do is put borders around everything so that I can figure out the reason for this issue. This means add style "border: 2px solid green" or any variation to the text (and possibly eventually something like text-align and also adding a border to the container itself (and eventually possibly changing its width or finding a different method to realign it)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your column

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```

and this to your text container

```
alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
```

So all code will be like this

```
     return   Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
         elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: new Center(child: new Text('Create',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat", color: Colors.black))),
    leading: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_back, 
      color: Colors.black, 
    ),
    ),
       ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
         children: <Widget>[
            Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
           Divider(
              height: 2,
          color: Colors.red,
          ),
            SizedBox(
            height: 17.0,
            ),
        Container(
            // margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0),

             alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
             child: Text('Create')
           )
         ],
       )

          ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the container as the child of Align. If you want to align every element to the left then you can just use :

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children:[])
```